# Ansible detect changes in certain files after `yum update` and do a reboot

Tags: ansible

While using ansible-playbook to manage VPS, I have task to run `yum update` using `yum` module.  The thing is, the VPS are initially CentOS 6.2 and it will upgrade to CentOS 6.5 (which is what I want), and then I want to do a reboot after this because there are some big changes, and I want that happen only after some big chagnes because I don't want to reboot every time there is some unimportant package updates.

In ansible, is it possible to detect such big changes, e.g., /etc/redhat-release will be changed by `yum update`, and then reboot if the big changes are found.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can implement it if you install `centos-release` package separately and when this action happens use `notify` to reboot your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can try something like this:

```
---
- name: Reboot Server Playbook
  hosts: all
  user: ambot
  sudo: True


  tasks:

    - name: Do an upgrade
      command: yum upgrade -y

    - name: Check what the new version is
      shell:  lsb_release -r | awk '{print $2}'
      register: new_release

    - name: Reboot
      command: /sbin/reboot
      when: ansible_distribution_version != new_release.stdout
```

The above will reboot the server if the CentOS release has changed. It's also using the `ansible_distribution_version` from the ansible facts variables populated initially the first time your playbook runs. 
Add -y in yum upgrade command, so process is not stuck waiting for confirmation in stdin from ansible.
To see the ansible facts on your localhost you can run something like:

```
ansible localhost -m setup
```

[Possible solution to regenerate facts in a playbook]

```
 # You can try this to store the initial version
 vars:
    current_os_version: $ansible_distribution_version


 tasks:

    - name: Regenerate facts ?
      setup: filter=*
```

Comment: This playbook will reboot server on every single run after the upgrade, but not before, probably not something @icando wants..

Comment: @Rico, this is very cool and I'll accept.  Before that, I'd like to confirm if it is possible to re-generate facts after `yum update`.  I mean, instead of running `lsb_release`, is it possible to ask ansible to re-check the hosts status and get an updated version of facts?

Comment: @icando I'm not really sure if you can do as I haven't seen it anywhere in the docs. However, you can try what I edited above, what I'm not really sure is if it overrides the previous fact gathering that happens when you initially run the playbook. Let me know if it works!

Comment: @icando btw, the above should be another question on SO

Comment: @Rico, ok accepted it.  I don't even know how to store the previous ansible_distribution_version to some variable, so your old way is better to me.

Comment: @icando I just added a way that you can store the variable initially just in case you give it a try.

Comment: @Rico, your way should work.  But the problem is, I am writing the tasks inside roles/xxx/tasks/main.yml, which means I have to put the `vars:` section in some yml in root directory.  Is there a way to keep the `vars:` inside the `tasks/main.yml`, so that the variable definition is close to where it is used?   Thanks.